# Как получить путь к папке "Документы" Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Использую `Xamarin`. Нужно получить путь к папке с документами (обычно она всегда называется "Мои документы"). Папке именно телефона, а не моего приложения. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);` [почитайте здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/6.1.php)

Comment: @Bulson, то что вы предложили не работает. И вот почему: `"/data/user/0/com.vadimshahray.testermobileapp/files/tickets_db.db"`. Вот какой путь я получаю используя данный метод. Этот путь указывает на папку приложения, а не на папку "Мои документы" всего устройства.

Comment: А что в андроиде есть такая папка? Я чет такую папку в своем телефоне не наблюдаю.

Comment: @Bulson, да есть. Я даже нашел как ней подобраться [вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows). Вкратце так `Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath`

Comment: Это вы называете `"Мои документы`? Это внешнее хранилище вообще то. `Мои документы` чисто виндовая фишка. В андроиде такого нет.

Comment: @Bulson, папка-то называется "Документы"/"Мои документы" в проводнике